# Change the property of a class in hover

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-selectors

**I want to change css property of a class on hover of another class in css**

```
  #_nav li {
    display:inline;
    text-decoration:none;
    padding-top:5vh;
    line-height:8vh;
    margin-right:5vh;
    cursor:pointer;
    }
   
    #_nav li:hover + #drop{
    color:blue;

    }
    #drop{
         color:red;
         }
```

> when i do hover on
>
> ## _nav_li
>
> i want color of #drop to get blue

Comment: Please provide a jsFiddle or any other demo link?

Comment: use   `#_nav li:hover  #drop{
    color:blue;

    }` without `+`

Comment: You need to include the HTML structure of the relevant CSS, please [edit] your post and include it, as it's an important detail to answer this question

Comment: do `#drop` is a child of  `#_nav li` ???

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change property of all instances of element on hover (CSS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10337020/change-property-of-all-instances-of-element-on-hover-css)

Comment: #_nav li:hover #drop{ color:blue; } worked Thanks

Comment: #nageen_nayak bro before asking a question we could not patrol whole stakeoverflow some time we need ans quickly.if u think its a copy then it would be unintentionally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `+` before `#drop` and 
Try this

```
#_nav_li:hover #drop {
  color: blue;
}
```

Comment: **this worked but if i write**  `#_nav li:hover #li a{color:blue}` then it do nothing

Comment: because you don't have an li element with id="li"; #_nav li:hover li a{color:blue}

Comment: `#` is place before id_value and `.` is place before class_name in CSS. SO if you have `id="li" ` then only u can use `#li` else use `li`only

Answer (score 0):

You can try this to change color on hoover

```
._nav_li:hover #drop{
    color:#DDD;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
 $( ".nav" ).hover(
    function() {
       $("#drop").css("color", "blue");
    };
</script>
```